# Calling a function from a different view using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My issue is that I have a button on one view, that I would like to hide from the function of another view.

I.e.

Calling view

```
@if (ViewBag.TestFinished== true)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        // hideButton();    - but the button is in a different view.
        closeModal();
    </script>
}
```

and the line from the view containing the button

```
<button type="button" class="full-width" data-
toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Take test</button>
```

I'm not sure that this can be done hence the question, but I have spent most of today googling for a solution to the problem and have come up with nothing.

Thanks

Edit: Silly of me not to mention that the view I want to trigger the event from is a partial.

Edit 2:

I've tried setting up an event from the calling partial view and a listener on the button's home view like so, but with no joy.

Event trigger

```
@if (ViewBag.TestFinished == true)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">           
        $.event.trigger('isFinished', true);

        closeModal();
    </script>
}
```

Listener

```
$(document).on('isFinished',
    function HideTestBtn() {
        $('#takeTestBtn').hide();
})
```

Comment: If it's in a different view then how is it not already hidden?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: What does your hideButton() method do? If both partial views are rendered on the same page can't you just select the button using a querySelector for some unique attribute and hide it like any other html element?

Comment: the view that the button is on isn't a partial. it calls a modal which is the view I want to hide the button from. the hidebutton() is meant as a call to the other view, but clearly my understanding is very rudimentary

Comment: Is "the button" unique on the page?  if so, give it an ID and reference it directly. (which is another way of putting what @Joe said).  Alternatives: namespace your javascript methods and call it via a namespace (too broad for a comment) or raise an event that you want to hide the button and have your button's view's code listen for the event (most flexible).

Comment: @freedomn-m I'll update my question with what I've tried to do so far with regards to your last suggestion (listening for the event). Maybe you could steer me in the right direction based on that.

Comment: try to create a function in your `js`. For example: `button1` if this button is click make a code that will hide the button that you want to hide. `button2` unhide the button that you hide. Sorry im not clear in what you want.